# Difference between Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.DueDate and Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.FinishDate of a work item

Tags: tfs, agile, tfs-workitem, tfs-process-template

I wonder the difference between using the field `Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.DueDate` or `Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.FinishDate` while customizing a work item in Team Foundation Server.

Answer (score 1):

You can find both fields in the [Work Item Field Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997792.aspx). The DueDate is a field which users enter in the UI of Team Explorer or Web Access. The FinishDate is the Automatically calculated end-date if you have Project or Project Server integration enabled on your project.